# WHM/cPanel differented bandwidth count

Tags: linux

there are two kinds of traffic in my country: internal and external. All traffic inside of the country is free, but all outside traffic is enormously expensive.
So I need WHM/cPanel to count all external traffic, but I don't need to count any internal traffic.
Is there any ideas to make it right?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns the use of shared web hosting by end users or resellers, rather than the administration of web hosting.

Answer (score 1):

No cPanel can't do this out of the box, and it would require it to GEOIP every IP which isn't feasibly possible. You would have to write your own stats plugin that would require an expensive GEOIP database.

Comment: @evolver Really this is something you would need your ISP to tell you - GeoIP is not very accurate (and almost certainly ***not*** how you're actually billed). You need to examine the actual traffic and destination networks. This is normally done using Netflow or a similar information-gathering system.